# How to output C# project release version to a totally different folder?

Tags: .net, path, output

I used to be able to do this in the old .csproj style, where one can explicitly specify different output folders for Debug and Release versions. For example, Debug can be under bin\Debug, while Release can be under C:\Production. I have not found a way to accomplish the same in the new SDK style project files. Is it possible? If not, is there a way to config the compile button to copy the Release version to a different folder after compiling?

--config of the old style project file

```
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
      <!-- snip -->
      <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
      <!-- snip -->
      <OutputPath>..\..\Production\</OutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
```